# Why is there a list of known WiFi networks in my airodrop-ng output?

Tags: wifi

[image]

As you can see that in the second list -visible devices, if I am not mistaken- the top device is my main laptop, this output is from a different laptop that is, of course, not connected to any networks (otherwise `airmon-ng` wouldn't start).

How/where does it get this list of networks the computer has connected to? And is this a problem security wise?

Comment: Those would be "probes" and the output indicates. Your device is actively asking if those networks are available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called **"Probe Request"** and it is a special frame sent by a client station requesting information from either a specific access point, specified by SSID, or all access points in the area, specified with the broadcast SSID.

You can read more information about this [here](http://mrncciew.com/2014/10/27/cwap-802-11-probe-requestresponse/).

> How/where does it get this list of networks the computer has connected
>   to?

It's a list with all known networks your device has successfully connected and marked as "Auto-Connect" by your system.

> is this a problem security wise?

Yes, because an attacker could reply to the probe request with a fake AP, created only to sniff your data. It's possible to perform this with a lot of tools, even with your own OS, creating a hotspot with the same name as the network your computer is probing.

I recommend you reading [this](https://hak5.org/episodes/haktip-23) and taking a look at [WifiPhiser](https://github.com/sophron/wifiphisher).

And no, you cannot disable this, because it's essential to inter-AP roaming.